# .NET GetThumbnailImage is not keeping metadata

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a web service that creates an thumbnail of any image uploaded, but all the thumbnails are rotated by 90 degrees. I know this is because of the metadata not being shared with the new image.

How do I set the meta data of the new image to match that of the original picture?

The code is simple:

```
        // Load image
        Image origImage = Image.FromFile(tempFilePath);

        // Compute thumbnail size
        Size thumbSize = GetThumbnailSize(origImage);

        // Get thumbnail
        Image thumbImage = origImage.GetThumbnailImage(thumbSize.Width, thumbSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I tried using things like the code below, but of course it doesn't work.

```
thumbImage.SetPropertyItem(origImage.GetPropertyItem(0x0112));
```

After fighting for a while I gave up on trying to set the meta data on the thumbnail so I did the following to fix the rotation:

```
try
        {
            switch (BitConverter.ToInt16(origImage.GetPropertyItem(0x0112).Value, 0))
            {
                case 1:
                    thumbImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //rft = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
                    thumbImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //rft = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
                    thumbImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    //rft = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
                    thumbImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;

            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Now all my thumbnails are formatted correctly I just hope it doesn't come back to bite me when I add support for Android devices to my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
foreach(PropertyItem propItem in origImage.PropertyItems)
{
  thumbImage.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
}
```

Comment: Nope. thumbnail is still 90 degrees off.

Comment: If you inspect the thumbImage in the debugger, has the properties been set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I tested like bellow and it works for me.

```
thumbImage.Save("without-metadata.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

thumbImage.SetPropertyItem(origImage.GetPropertyItem(0x0112));
thumbImage.Save("with-metadata.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

var withoutImage = Image.FromFile("without-metadata.jpg");
// false, of course
Debug.WriteLine("Has 0x0112 property?: {0}", withoutImage.PropertyIdList.Any(o => o == 0x0112));

var withImage = Image.FromFile("with-metadata.jpg");
// true, of course
Debug.WriteLine("Has 0x0112 property?: {0}", withImage.PropertyIdList.Any(o => o == 0x0112));
```

Could you link an image file that doesn't work?